# Bootstrap Pagination -- How to insert bootstrap in code?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pagination, django-templates

I have a django template with this code:

```
{% load bootstrap %}
{% if is_paginated %}
{% load i18n %}
<div class="pagination">
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}{{ getvars }}{{ hashtag }}" class="prev">&lsaquo;&lsaquo; {% trans "previous" %}</a>
    {% else %}
        <span class="disabled prev">&lsaquo;&lsaquo; {% trans "previous" %}</span>
    {% endif %}
    {% for page in pages %}
        {% if page %}
            {% ifequal page page_obj.number %}
                <span class="current page">{{ page }}</span>
            {% else %}
                <a href="?page={{ page }}{{ getvars }}{{ hashtag }}" class="page">{{ page }}</a>
            {% endifequal %}
        {% else %}
            ...
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
        <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}{{ getvars }}{{ hashtag }}" class="next">{% trans "next" %} &rsaquo;&rsaquo;</a>
    {% else %}
        <span class="disabled next">{% trans "next" %} &rsaquo;&rsaquo;</span>
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Please tell me how can I insert bootstrap pagination here?
I have tried giving `class="pagination"`, but still unable to bootstrap it!
Kindly help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Just crossed the same bridge yesterday. The key is that the pagination class needs to be on a  not a .

So swap out -->

```
    <div class="pagination"> 
    for
    <ul class="pagination">
```

Then put

tags around your pagelinks

```
    <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_pag ..... blah </a></li>
```

From bootstrap docs:

```
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
     </ul>
```